# Django: template needs to return per-item result based on who you are

Tags: django

As my template loops through a list of `Forum` objects provided by the View, I need to present a value *("number of posts ...")* that will depend on who the user is – and of course, if he is anonymous.

So, I basically need to call a function, from the template, whose arguments are "the current `Forum` object" and "the current request – thus giving me access to the user."  In order to return the appropriate integer as seen by this user.

How do I do that, the Django way?

Comment: can you also post your template and view from what you have tried, we must see a (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out

Comment: I would go by (1) passing the function to the template from view (never tried this, or (2) registering custo template

Comment: As the template is populated from the view, couldn't it be easier to match the values from the view too ? like zipping user and forum objects for example ? We need much more details to help you here